# How to move application window to current workspace?

Tags: python, compiz

My application has "Bring to current desktop" option in indicator menu. Now, moving windows across workspaces is nice and easy if you are not using Compiz.

My question is how could I bring application window to current desktop. Application is written in Python and GTK+. I tried using *Present* method of gtk.Window but then window grabs focus and nothing else happens (window is not actually presented to user). I also tried playing with *wnck*, but that method works only when Compiz is not running.

Any idea?